# How get a value looking only for last day of a given month available?

Tags: excel

In column A I have a list of dates and in column B I have values:

```
A            B
01/01/2020   10
28/01/2020   20
03/02/2020   30
04/03/2020   40
```

How to get (for example value 20) looking only for last day of a given month (for example January) available?

Comment: Would you like to do that with a macro?

Comment: If not is possible with a formula then yes.

Comment: You can use the Pivot Table for this. Rows will be the `Date` field and you can set `Max Value` on `Values Panel`.

Comment: Use a formula to match the relevant date, then index into the value column to return the value.  Show us what you have tried, and where you have run into problems.

Comment: Yes, I should think Maxifs to get the date then vlookup or index/match to get the value

Answer (score 0):

You can use MAXIFS to get the last date in the month and VLOOKUP to get the matching value e.g. if the month number is in C2:

```
=VLOOKUP(MAXIFS(A2:A5,A2:A5,">="&DATE(2020,C2,1),A2:A5,"<="&EOMONTH(DATE(2020,C2,1),0)),A2:B5,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

EOMONTH with a zero gives you the last day in the current month (i.e. 31/1/20 in this case)